# Differential equations cannot spot any standard form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to approach the Differential equation $$2(x-y \, \sin(2x)) \, dx + (3y^{2} + \cos(2x)) \, dy=0$$ I cannot see whether the equation is in any standard form. Initial steps and/or hints appreciated.

Comment: Have you heard of "exact differential equation"?

Comment: The DE is in the form $M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=0.$ What is the partial derivative of $M$ with rspect to $y$? What is the partial derivative of $N$ with respect to $x$?

Comment: Is x and y supposed to be some function of time or something? Your notation looks a lot like a differential form.

Comment: Thank you. I had already done it. It was very easy infact.

Comment: @user2662833. Divide the equation formally with $dx$ and — *voilà* — a differential equation appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$2(x-y \, \sin(2x)) \, dx + (3y^{2} + \cos(2x)) \, dy=0$$
$$2(x-y \, \sin(2x)) + (3y^{2} + \cos(2x)) y'=0$$
$$2x +(y\cos(2x))'+(y^3)'=0$$
Integrate 
$$x^2 +y\cos(2x)+y^3=K$$

Comment: Thank you... I'd already solved it by the same method.

Comment: yw @ArkaSeth...